# Nothings happens on Selenium click

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests

I have this code:

```
StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
timer.start();
while (timer.getTime() < 10000) {
    try {
        addClose.click();
        break;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (WebDriverException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is when the click is done, nothing is actually happening on the page (like the click was never done). But there were no errors/exceptions that happened on click. How could I solve this?

This thing was happening even before, and my way of dealing with this was to have some validation whether something happened on the page, and if not, do the click again (the same way I'am dealing with these two exceptions).

Comment: The first thing to check is that you are actually clicking the correct element.

Comment: Of course it is and I checked it. If I just add Thread.sleep before the click it will be ok

Comment: then you need to research more into explicit waits. also, "of course it is" - @alecxe is just trying to help you.  it's prudent even to ask the most obvious questions.

Comment: I was trying many things with explicit waits, but it did not help. Later after asking the question I deleted catch (NoSuchElementException e) and added wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated. With "of course it is" I really just meant "you are 100% right". It wasn't my intention to be impolite, especially with the guy who is trying to help

Comment: as @sircapsalot points out, if inserting a Thread.sleep() just before the click will always cause the click to work, then that indicates the problem is that the attempt to click is happening before all necessary javascript, or other objects have completely loaded.  You might check the browser console content after a failure to see if errors are reported there, giving you a clue about what's happening.

Comment: If you are using protractor you could put in a `browser.waitForAngular()` instead of an explicit wait.